# With two lists, how do I plot elements from one, based of an element of the other?

Tags: python, list, overlay

I am trying to plot spikes that occurred in my data.

I have two lists, one that is the **time** of each spike, and the second is which cluster group that spike belongs to.

I am trying to plot all of the spike **times** for cluster A separately from the spike times of cluster B.

The lists are the same lengths and look something like this,
[0.01, 0.05, 0.09, 0.10 etc.....]
[a, a, a, b, etc......]

I can load all the spikes from my MAT file

```
all_spikes=mat_data['Timestamps']
```

But when I try to specifically plot the spikes labeled A on my second list, I still get all of the spikes.

I have tried

```
selected_spike = all_spikes if ['assigned'==A] else NotImplemented
```

and

```
selected_spike = all_spikes - ['assigned'==B]
```

Comment: What did you come up with?

Comment: Have you tried boolean masking?